Is it safe to carry Butane canisters bought at sea level up to 5500m?
I am planning a trip to the Everest Base Camp in a few days.
I am planning to carry with me a portable stove and 4 Butane Canisters, to make soup and stuff.
About Butane Canisters:

These are bought at sea level. Would they be safe to carry at altitudes of 5500 meters? Do these things explode at high altitude?

What is the safest way to pack gas canisters, and where in the rucksack should they be put (I would not like to have them near the head and the spine, but that's where the Rucksack usually is.)




Yes, they are safe at this altitude. I don't know the maximum altitude, but the atmospheric pressure at 10,000 m (higher than Everest at 8848.1 m) is approx 26.4 kPa, which is about 1/4 of that at sea level (generally defined as 100 kPa). At 5,000 m this is about 55 kPa. Neither of these is a problem for the canister itself to contain, though you can get an overpressure situation which might result in some leakage from the valve. You won't get a catastrophic failure with shards of metal or anything.
Thanks to @JonCuster for the comment. The reason this is so is because they are designed to withstand heat. As the temperature increases, the gas expands and creates greater pressure. Most manufacturers seem to recommend storage below 50 C (120F) because the pressure increases the risk of canister failure. At room temperatures the pressure is about 2-3 atmospheres and increases as the temperature goes up. The canister is engineered to contain the pressure at 50 C, which is a massive compared to the difference in pressure between sea level and 5500 m altitude.
However, you have bigger problems than pressure with butane at altitude, and that is temperature. Butane boils at about -0.5°C (31°F), which is only just below freezing. Isobutane boils at -11.7°C (11°F) and propane at -42°C (-43.6°F), so both of these will be a better choice than pure butane at altitude, especially when you consider that the canisters cool when gas is released.



Make sure the canisters don't get crushed - put them inside something like a cooking pan. These are usually strong enough to not get crushed, and have the added bonus of having your cooking materials all in the same place. Heavy stuff like cooking gear generally goes upper back, close to the spine. Inside a pan there is very little risk of accidental rupture.


Are you sure about your pressures, in point #1? I thought the pressure at 10km was about 25-30kPa, but it looks like you're suggesting that that's the difference in atmospheric pressure between sea level and 10,000m. Pressure at sea-level is ~100kPa, so that would imply 10km pressure is ~75kPa, which I'm sure isn't right. Or have I misunderstood? (Doesn't affect your conclusion, obvs)

the link for pressure states that it gives the "Air pressure at Elevation 10000 m" to be 26.4 kPa, not the difference in pressure.

@SusanW Quite right - was writing something else and then forgot to change it...

@njzk2 as SusanW had already commented...

@bob1 Cool! Wasn't sure if it was because I was wearing the wrong glasses :-)

Wow, that bit about boiling point of butane seems serious. I can't fid any propane cannisters online in my geography. How serious is this issue with Butane? What can I expect to happen to butane canisters at subzero temperatures?

@Iskander At cold conditions, it can happen that your stove won't work due to lack of pressure. This is less likely to happen for a full canister and more of a problem for an half-empty one. There are gas mixtures specifically for colder conditions that contain mainly propane and isopropane. Depending on the manufacturer, these may be called winter gas or something similar

@Iskander Try freezing it overnight then seeing if the stove still performs the same. If so, it's a blend that contains propane and it should be fine. But confirm it with more outdoorsy people. The point is that not everything labeled butane is butane. I bought some "butane" that was just labeled that way for product differentiation (so they could sell a cheap one and an expensive one).

At 70F a butane cylinder contains about 34 psi, down to 22 psi at 60F. At over 100F the pressure would get closer to 100 psi, and the container is engineered for that. Reducing the external pressure by even 1 atmosphere (taking it into space!) would not impact the safety of the cylinder at all.

@bob1 indeed...

@JonCuster Excellently put - I was trying to get that point across, but couldn't get my head around it being an increase in temp that is a problem with an ascent.

The canisters are (hopefully) safe at sea level within any plausible temperature range. So, they shouldn't explode when reaching 50 °C.
The stress of the canister can be expressed as the pressure difference between inside and outside.
At 50 °C, the inner pressure created by pure butane is around 5 bar (500 kPa), and at sea level the outside pressure is 1 bar (100 kPa), so we can assume that the canister survives a 4 bar pressure difference.
Even if you were to "completely" leave the atmosphere (outer pressure zero), the pressure difference would only rise to 5 bar, and you could compensate for that by making sure the temperature stays about 10 degrees lower.
As most prabably, the temperature in high mountains is considerably lower than at sea level, don't worry about the canisters' safety. But (as Bob1 answered) they might be useless because of a lack of pressure.

This doesn't answer the question.  Temperature isn't mentioned in the question and isn't relevant.

@Chenmunka I entirely disagree; temperature and altitude are intimately related. If you ascend a mountain it gets much colder and the performance of the fuel is related to temperature by reduction of effective pressure.
